# What's the meaning of 'What do I care?'

Tags: meaning

I guess that expression is used when someone is talking about something that he/she doesn't want to care about, I mean, 'Why do I have to care about? I don't want.' 
Is my guess correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's pretty much what it means.  It also implies "What does that have to do with me—why **should** I care?"

In any case, it is a **rhetorical question**, and often **sarcastic**.

Comment: Also worth noting is that it's often used sarcastically.

Answer (score 1):

It's another piece of pop-culture slang from decades ago that's misquoted. The phrase originally was,"Why should I care?", which actually makes sense, but more simply could be expressed with, "I don't care," because the question, indeed, is rhetorical.

Answer (score 1):

> What do I care?

In spoken discourse, this is almost certainly going to be spoken as "What do *I* care?", where the speaker emphasizes *I* to make a distinction between the speaker and the other party. Using this phrase shows your indifference to what the other party is interested in. I believe it is meant to be ironic, but using this phrase will often come across as mean-spirited.

For example:

> -- There is a discount on sliced bread at the supermarket! 
>   -- What do I care? (= I understand you have an interest in that, but to me it is of little or no consequence.)

A similar phrase is "What does *he* know?", used to shows a contrast in knowledge in an ironic way.

> -- I think we should go that way.
>   -- What do you know? We normally end up lost when we follow your advice.
>   
>   -- This looks like genuine gold. But what do I know? I'm no expert.

Answer (score 1):

It means simply, "I don't care" or "How does that apply to me?"

It's generally considered a rude phrase.